# Xcode 4 embed app version into the iOS app

Tags: xcode4, ios4, runtime, iphone-4

Is it possible to access **the app version** that I specify in the xcode project setting from within the application?

I'm trying to create an auto-updating "About" view controller, and it would be nice to receive **bug reports listing the version of the app.**

I know this can be done with built-in constant, but I'm wandering if there's a better way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read you Info.plist in your main bundle for the according key.

Sample code:

```
NSBundle     *bundle    = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString     *infosPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *infosDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:infosPath];

NSLog(@"CFBundleVersion : %@" , [infosDict valueForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]);
```

I just tested this code and its working fine. Do a right-clik on you Info.plist to display raw key names.

Also, I was testing this code with a plist with spaces in its names, which gave me 'null' for the infosPath. Deleting the space solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I can get the version number that has to be incremented for App store upload:

```
NSString* version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```